# Pod Completion without completing process

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a cluster running some jobs, there's a job that executes a pod. that pod is completed while in process, like 1+3=5 now it should display 5 but it stops in 1+3 and its status is to complete. **I don't know what can cause a pod to complete without executing the whole code.** any help or thoughts on it would help a lot.

**Detail:**

I have a case now,

```
console.log("Opening in ECS ");<<--in one case pod successfully terminates here -->>
try {
    await funcy1();<<-- an async function -->>
    console.log("opening in ECS end");<--in second case pod successfully terminates here-->>
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}
```

now the pod is completed at stated line, if there's an error it should be thrown (which is logged). But I cannot see any log. It's just pod is completed on specified line which shouldn't be the case.

some erros from pods descriptions are:

```
 State:        Terminated
 Reason:       Error
 Exit Code:    255
```

and

```
 State:        Terminated
 Reason:       Error
 Exit Code:    137
```

and

```
 State:        Terminated
 Reason:       Completed
 Exit Code:    0
```

Comment: Please add some more details - at this level of detail it is almost impossible to help

Comment: I've added the deatils.

Comment: It is still not enough to analyze your issue. Please post *logs* of pods here for further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not specifying resources of the pod, just thought it can help someone.